# How to display the tabs when click the back button from hided tab view controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabview

I created a tab bar controller and from one tab item I gave segue to the navigation view controller. And I create a some view controllers attached to navigation controller. So in one view controller I don't need a tabs so in that controller I wrote to  hide the tab bar controller that is  `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true`.

When I click the back button of navigation controller from hided tab view controller to previous controller, it doesn't show the tab bar items in previous controllers. But I needed  tabs in all view controller except in one view controller. Why  does it not show the tabs?

This is my story board :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in the VC that's before the one you hide the tab in

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`in the view controller which you don't need tabs. Fits your situation.

```
let controller = ViewControllerTwo()
controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

A little more explanation:

`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true` globally changed the `self.tabBarController`'s property `hideTabBar` across its children controllers stack.